# Using Flex Box to Organize Material in a Box HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have it so that the images show up in the in my premade box that I created. Right now, they are too wide and showing up outside my width of 50em. Also, they are pretty big height wise, and I don't know if that is just a change of the picture or the code. I'm using flexbox for this.

Right now, without the images in there, it looks like they are all on one line from using the wrap, but once the images are in, then it stops working right.

```css
main{
    width:50em;
    border-style:solid;
    display:flex;
}

.images{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 1 25em;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- A meta element naming the Unicode character set you want the browser to use (UTF-8). -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- A link to reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flex.css">
</head>
    
<body>
    <main class="wrapper">
        
        <header id="images">
            <img src="student-misc-02.jpg" alt="student1">
            <img src="student-misc-06.jpg" alt="student1">
            <img src="student-misc-08.jpg" alt="student1">
            <img src="student-misc-12.jpg" alt="student1">
            <img src="student-misc-19.jpg" alt="student1">
            <img src="student-misc-20.jpg" alt="student1">
        </header>    
        
    </main>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you need 3 columns? And you had used `#images` as an ID on the HTML header. But are using as class `.images` on the CSS code

Comment: @IcaroHeimig I was trying to do 3 pictures per line which you did below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the CSS code to match your HTML code. Also, in some of your edits, you showed as 3 columns, the last CSS rule try to reproduce those 3 columns layout.

```css
main {
  width: 50em;
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
}

/* fix the selector to match yout html code using id, not class */
#images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 25rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* If you need the three columns as your original question */
#images img {
  width: 33%; 
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- A meta element naming the Unicode character set you want the browser to use (UTF-8). -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- A link to reset -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flex.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="wrapper">

    <header id="images">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="student1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="student1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="student1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="student1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="student1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="student1">
    </header>

    <section class="title">
      <!--<h1>XD Rountable 2019 Event Calendar</h1>-->
    </section>

    <footer>
    </footer>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```